# Excel VBA: Adding objects to a collection within a class

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections

I am trying to create a class (named ClassSection) that contains a collection (named DefectCollection). It needs a function to add items to that collection but I'm having trouble making it work. I get Error 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set."

I have looked at the other answers on here, which is what got me this far, but I don't understand what I'm missing.

Here is the class module code:

```
Public DefectCollection As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialise()
    Set DefectCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Public Function AddDefect(ByRef defect As CDefect)
    DefectCollection.Add defect [<---- error 91]
End Function
```

And here is the code that calls the function: ('defect' is another class, which works fine - I want each 'ClassSection' to be able to hold an unlimited number of 'defects')

```
Dim SC As Collection
Dim section As ClassSection
Set SC = New Collection

Dim SurveyLength As Double

For Each defect In DC
    SurveyLength = WorksheetFunction.Max(SurveyLength, defect.Pos, defect.EndPos)
Next defect

SurveyLength = Int(SurveyLength)

For i = 0 To numSurveys
    For j = 0 To SurveyLength
        Set section = New ClassSection
        section.ID = CStr(j & "-" & dates(i))
        SC.Add Item:=section, Key:=section.ID
    Next j
Next i


Dim meterage As Double

For Each defect In DC
    meterage = Int(defect.Pos)
    Set section = SC.Item(meterage & "-" & defect.SurveyDate)
    section.AddDefect defect
Next defect
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Private Sub Class_Initialise()` should be `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`

Comment: British spelling!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the `DefectCollection` is `Nothing`. This is due to the fact that you mispelled the initalization method:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialise() '<-- it's with "Z", not "S"
```

Hence, the initialization of the class is never called, the object remain `Nothing` by default and the method fails when trying to add an object to `Nothing`